# Prove $\cos x +\cos y = 2\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $$\cos(x) + \cos(y) = 2\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})$$ holds true for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Even though I managed to prove its brother $\sin(x) + \sin(y)$, I haven't been able to tackle this one.
Important identities needed for the proof:
$$\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$$
$$\cos(x-y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)$$
Let's go:
$$2\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2}) = 2\cos(\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{y}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{y}{2}) = $$
$$ = 2(\cos(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{y}{2}) - \sin(\frac{x}{2})\sin(\frac{y}{2}))(\cos(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{y}{2}) + \sin(\frac{x}{2})\sin(\frac{y}{2})) = $$
$$ = 2(\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})\cos^2(\frac{y}{2}) - \sin^2(\frac{x}{2})\sin^2(\frac{y}{2})) = $$
$$ = 2\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})\cos^2(\frac{y}{2}) - 2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})\sin^2(\frac{y}{2})$$
Now I tried, I believe, almost every possible replacement by deriving from $\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$ and sadly nothing worked.

Comment: Hint: Use $\cos x=2\cos^2(x/2)-1=1-2\sin^2(x/2)$ to continue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\cos(a+b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b)$$
$$\cos(a-b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) + \sin(a)\sin(b)$$

Adding the two,
$$\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b) = 2\cos(a)\cos(b)$$

Setting $a = \frac{x+y}{2}$ and $b = \frac{x-y}{2}$, we get
$$\cos(x) + \cos(y) = 2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$
as desired.

Comment: Oh my god. How was I supposed to come up with this!? Thank you.

Comment: @tomashauser mathematics is often deceiving.

Comment: This proof is one of the most elegant ones I've come come across this site.

Answer (score 2):

Add these equations:

$\cos x=\cos\dfrac{x+y}2\cos\dfrac{x-y}2-\sin\dfrac{x+y}2\sin\dfrac{x-y}2$

$\cos y=\cos\dfrac{x+y}2\cos\dfrac{x-y}2+\sin\dfrac{x+y}2\sin\dfrac{x-y}2$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $ x \rightarrow (x+y)/2 $ and $y \rightarrow (x-y)/2$ in the second & third equations. Now add them together.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is also an exercise in McMullen's "Trig Identities". Here is the book’s approach ( with hints from the author).
The start is similar to the OP solution.

Show:

$ \displaystyle \cos x + \cos y = 2\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})\cos(\frac{x-y}{2}) = \\ 2\cos(\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{y}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{y}{2}) = \\ 2\left [\cos \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{y}{2} - \sin \frac{x}{2}\sin \frac{y}{2} \right]\left [\cos \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{y}{2} + \sin \frac{x}{2}\sin \frac{y}{2} \right]$

Now multiply the two terms.

$ \displaystyle = 2\left [\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\cos^2 \frac{y}{2} + \cos \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{y}{2}\sin \frac{x}{2}\sin \frac{y}{2} - \cos \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{y}{2}\sin \frac{x}{2}\sin \frac{y}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{y}{2} -\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\sin^2 \frac{y}{2} \right]$

Simplify, by adding like terms

$ \displaystyle = 2\left [\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\cos^2 \frac{y}{2}  -\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\sin^2 \frac{y}{2} \right]$

Key step : Distribute $2$ and expand

$\displaystyle = \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\cos^2 \frac{y}{2} + \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\cos^2 \frac{y}{2}  -\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\sin^2 \frac{y}{2} -\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\sin^2 \frac{y}{2}$

Apply the pythagorean identities

$ \displaystyle = \left( 1 - \sin^2 \frac{x}{2} \right)\cos^2 \frac{y}{2} + \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\left( 1 - \sin^2 \frac{y}{2} \right)  -\left( 1 - \cos^2 \frac{x }{2} \right)\sin^2 \frac{y}{2} -\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\left( 1 - \cos^2 \frac{y}{2} \right)$

$ \displaystyle = \cos^2 \frac{y}{2} - \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\cos^2 \frac{y}{2} + \cos^2 \frac{x}{2} - \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\sin^2 \frac{y}{2}  -\sin^2 \frac{y}{2} + \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\sin^2 \frac{y}{2} -\sin^2 \frac{x}{2} + \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\cos^2 \frac{y}{2}$

Rearrange

$ \displaystyle\cos^2 \frac{y}{2} -\sin^2 \frac{y}{2} + \cos^2 \frac{x}{2} -\sin^2 \frac{x}{2} + \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\cos^2 \frac{y}{2}- \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\cos^2 \frac{y}{2}  + \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\sin^2 \frac{y}{2}   - \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\sin^2 \frac{y}{2} $

Simplify

$ \displaystyle \cos^2 \frac{y}{2} -\sin^2 \frac{y}{2} + \cos^2 \frac{x}{2} -\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}  $

$ \displaystyle \cos(2u) = \cos^2 u - sin ^ 2 u$

Now let $u = \frac{y}{2}$ Hence: $2u = y$

Thus: $ \displaystyle\cos y = \cos^2 \frac{y}{2} - sin ^ 2 \frac{y}{2}$  Similarly apply for $ \displaystyle x$

Finally

$ \displaystyle= \cos x + \cos y$